# How to delete attribute "hidden" in tag <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I need to upload file via Selenium webdriver.
But if I using something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Then I've got an error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 128 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

So I guess I need to remove attribute Hidden using js, and I found this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].removeAttribute('hidden');");
```

but it is not working for me.

This is the code I working on:

```
<label name="file" ng-model="file" ngf-accept="pattern" ngf-pattern="pattern" ngf-select="uploadSubmit($file)" ng-disabled="isUploadDisabled()" type="button" class="button button--large ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                <span translate="" class="button__text">Загрузить из файла .xls</span>
                <input type="file" hidden="" ng-disabled="isUploadDisabled()">
            </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

Try it :

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].removeAttribute('hidden'));
```

**OR**

```
if (document.all !== undefined)
{
   var allElements = document.all;
}
else
{
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
}

allElements[0].removeAttribute('hidden');
```

Comment: i've added a part of code, could you please check for my situation particulary

Comment: i have updated my answer, i have checked and then posted it so please care about that

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to remove the `hidden` attribute using JS approach through code, as Selenium is to be used to simulate the actual user actions. 
 
Like if the user clicks on any button and the site displays that `div`. i would recommend you to trigger the same component first and then use the hidden component once it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to add some wait time so that the element may be loaded in DOM.
Else try to make the element visible by using the below code.

```
WebElement element = yourWebDriverInstance.findElement(Locator);

((JavascriptExecutor) yourWebDriverInstance).executeScript(arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';, element);
```